# How to get the change text of <th> of the html the table React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, jsx

I want to change the value of table at the runtime, means user can change table header or table rows value manually.

I used contentEditable to change the table data directly by the user from the table, by I am unable to get the change input by the user, and always get old text which  shown in the table,how can I get the updated value of table in ReactJs

```
<table
  id="mytable"
  className="table table-striped table-nowrap dataTable"
  cellSpacing="0"
  width="100%"
>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {this.state.colarray.map((coldata, ind) => {
        return (
          <th key={ind} onChange={this.colchange}>
            <div contentEditable>{coldata}</div>
          </th>
        );
      })}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {console.log("rows", this.state.rowarray)}
    {this.state.rowarray.map((rowdata, ind) => {
      return (
        <tr id="somerow">
          {this.state.colarray.map((col, index) => {
            return (
              <td>
                <div contentEditable>{rowdata["item" + index]}</div>
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onClick={this.show}>button</button>
```

When the user clicks the `button.show()` function works, where I am trying to get the updated value but it always show old data of table,I have also used `onChange` event table header `<th>` trying to get the value but it also not works even the `colchange` is not called when I change in `<th>`.I want updated input which is entered by user on table how can I get?